# how do I choose between JComponent.revalidate and Container.validate

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am using WindowBuilder and Swing.  I am performing the following on a Swing JPanel:

```
java.awt.Container.setLayout()
java.awt.Container.removeAll()
java.awt.Container.add()
```

To finish I invoke:

`java.awt.Container.validate()` but I noticed that `javax.swing.JComponent.revalidate()` seems to do the same thing in practice.  I have not observed any difference in behaviour.  JPanel inherits from both Container and JComponent.  How do I choose between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 important differences:

- `JComponent#revalidate()` invalidates the component first which `Container#validate()` does not do.
- `JComponent#revalidate()` does not validate immediately, it adds the component to a list of invalid components and the `RepaintManager` will validate components in batches. This can improve performance when lots of validations are required.
- `JComponent#revalidate()` can be called from any thread, not just the event dispatch thread.

Unless you need an immediate effect (which is only needed in special situations), `JComponent#revalidate()` is preferrable.